# Trying to return a filter() value from an array of objects based on conditionals

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, javascript-objects

I'm trying to return only a part of my object as an array based on conditionals but I'm kinda stumped.

I have an array of objects and I want to return an array of names for each key : value they fit in.

I do get only the unique pairings but I'm returning the food key:value as well and all of it is still inside an object not a new array. Some insight would be greatly appreciated. Newer to coding.

```js
const organizeNames = function (foods) {
 let foodNames = foods.filter((names) => {
  if (names.food === 'oranges') {
  return names.name;
 }
});

console.log(foodNames);
};
console.log(
  organizeNames([
   { name: 'Samuel', food: 'oranges' },
   { name: 'Victoria', food: 'pizza' },
   { name: 'Karim', food: 'pizza' },
   { name: 'Donald', food: 'pizza' },
  ])
 );
```

Comment: Well you only have one `oranges` item, so that one object is the only one remaining...

Comment: `filter()` just filters the array, it doesn't change the elements. It just checks whether the call back returns a truthy value. Use `map()` to change the elements.

Comment: `organizeNames()` doesn't return anything, that's why you get `undefined` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close here. What you need to incorporate is `.map()` to map your list of objects to a list of names. Your filter part works, partly by accident, so I've fixed it to be more correct (`return names.food === 'oranges'`), and then once you have your list of objects that match 'oranges' for their food, you map that filtered list into a list of names by doing `.map(names => names.name)`

```js
const organizeNames = function (foods) {
  let foodNames = foods.filter((names) => {
    // only keep items whose .food property === 'oranges'
    return names.food === 'oranges'; // returns true or false
  }).map(names => {
    // map the filtered list of objects into a list of names by
    // returning just the object's .name property
    return names.name;
  });

  return foodNames;
};
console.log(
  organizeNames([
   { name: 'Samuel', food: 'oranges' },
   { name: 'Victoria', food: 'pizza' },
   { name: 'Karim', food: 'pizza' },
   { name: 'Donald', food: 'pizza' },
  ])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` callback function should just return `true` or `false`. Then you can use `map()` to get a specific property from each of the filtered items.

```js
const organizeNames = function(foods) {
  let foodNames = foods.filter((names) => names.food == 'oranges').map(names => names.name);
  return foodNames;
}

console.log(
  organizeNames([{
      name: 'Samuel',
      food: 'oranges'
    },
    {
      name: 'Victoria',
      food: 'pizza'
    },
    {
      name: 'Karim',
      food: 'pizza'
    },
    {
      name: 'Donald',
      food: 'pizza'
    },
  ])
);
```